# Does the destructor for unique_ptr get ran if exit is called?

Tags: c++

I have several places in my program where exit(0) is called. Will the destructors for my unique_ptr's be called, and deallocate the data on the heap before the program terminates?

Comment: Did you consider figuring this out yourself by creating a class that prints a message in its destructor, constructing it and making the pointer a `unique_ptr`, and then seeing what happens when you `exit`? Did you have any difficulties doing this experiment?

Comment: Depends on the scope of the unique_ptr.  If it is a globally constructed or static constructed variable, the destructor will be call through the `atexit` mechanism.  If the variable is local or a member variable of an object or a dependent member of such, then it will be leaked (but the memory is reclaimed by the operating system on termination).